# how to use common code repo depedencies in other micro services for local application development without generating .jar?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, gradle, intellij-idea

I am using intelliJ and gradle for my application development.

I have tried various options,

> When i tried using maven as build tool in IntelliJ, i am able to use
> common code in my other micro services without generating common.jar

Here is my code example:

1. Create two basic maven projects using *https://start.spring.io/*

   **C:/DemoRepo/demo-admin-service

   C:/DemoRepo/demo-common-code**
2. Taken both projects into IntelliJ from root folder (C://DemoRepo)
3. Provided demo-common-code dependency in demo-admin-service.

> ```
> pom.xml <dependency>  <groupId>com.demo</groupId>     <artifactId>demo-common-code</artifactId>   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>   <optional>true</optional> </dependency>
> ```

4. Did some changes, created few pojos at "demo-common-code", and did build
5. Verified at demo-admin-service, I am able to see all
   "demo-common-code" pojos at "demo-admin-service" without building
   any jar(demo-common-code.jar).

   Here cmmon.jar is not required to build everytime there is a change
   in common code. Maven is intelligent enough to read the common
   changes from my admin-service.

**This is really good.  This is what I want for my local spring boot micro service development.**

But

My project is using gradle. so with gradle I am not able to achieve same thing.
Every time I am forced to create a demo-common-code.jar for any common code changes and refer that jar from demo-admin-service, then only i am able to access latest demo-common-code repo changes.

This is impacting my local development.
How can I achieve the behavior which maven/pom.xml is exhibiting same thing i want with gradle as well in IntelliJ.

Please experts any suggestion?
Gradle is also most widely used build tool, so there should be a way we can achieve this behaviour.

Please suggest.

Comment: What about using a multi-module project?

Comment: @JFabianMeier, This for suggestion, Could you please give me any reference for the same.

Comment: See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html